# Java event oriented Socket library

Tags: java, sockets, client

I am looking for any good Socket library with events for Java. Mainly it should be used for client development. Server side is already finished (in other language).

Thank you very much.

Comment: Depending on your requirements, using plain Sockets may be all you need.

Comment: Yes, it is one of the possible ways. Just dont want to write something what is already done. Anyway thanks for the Mina mentioning.

Comment: `Apache Mina` used to be a more popular choice (AFAIK its older), but `Jboss Netty` now gets more results on google. ;)

Comment: You can try Extasys - Asynchronous TCP/UDP socket library. https://github.com/nsiatras/extasys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the best one is [jBoss Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty)

> The Netty project is an effort to provide an asynchronous event-driven
>   network application framework and tools for rapid development of
>   maintainable high performance & high scalability protocol servers &
>   clients.

Comment: +1: Netty has some benchmarks where they compare themselves with the best of the rest, you could look at those too.  Mina is also a popular choice.